# Fetch images from iCloud Photo Library PHImageManager

Tags: ios, swift4, photos

I currently have an issue where users that use iCloud Photo Library and pick an image that's not locally saved, the PHImageManager returns a blank image (nothing).
Is there a specific option to automatically download images that are stored only in iCloud?
(I use a custom CollectionView and PHImageManager)

Answer (score 8):

You could use the 'requestImageData' to download the image from iCloud:

Swift 4:

```
let manager = PHImageManager.default()
let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
requestOptions.resizeMode = .exact
requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat;

// Request Image
manager.requestImageData(for: asset, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (data, str, orientation, info) -> Void in
    // Do somethign with Image Data
})
```

If you're already using this to download the image, it looks like you need this option to download it from iCloud: `PHImageRequestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed`

For a bit more information, you can go to this link that I found:
[PHImageManager requestImageData with Photos iCloud Photo Library](https://diego.org/2016/10/29/phimagemanager-requestimagedata-with-photos-icloud-photo-library/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're having trouble getting images from iCloud via `PHImageManager` in addition to setting `PHImageRequestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed` make sure you're not connected through Charles Proxy, iCloud doesn't like that for some reason...